# How do I outline water with map.addLayer paint?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

Objective: Outline the water, the dark section, with the same line style as the terrain data.

Problem: I am likely trying to add the wrong data or getting the wrong layer ID. I've provided my code below, any help on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: TOPO MAP]

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('mapbox-terrain', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2'
    });
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'terrain-data',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'mapbox-terrain',
        'source-layer': 'contour',
        'layout': {
            'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
            },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#489EA9',
            'line-width': 2
            }
    });
    map.addSource('mapbox-streets', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox-streets-v7'
    });
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "water",
        'type': 'line',
        "source": "mapbox-streets",
        "source-layer": "water",
        'layout': {
            'line-cap': 'round',
            'line-join': 'round'
            },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#489EA9',
            'line-width': 2
            }
    });
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve or what you've tried so far.

Comment: @SteveBennett 'id': 'terrain-data' has line styling applied to it. I would like to apply the same styling to water, so that it is outlined just like the terrain contours. The water in the image is the darker part, and terrain is the light blue lines.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
 map.addLayer({
    'id': 'water-line-layer',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'water',
    'type': 'line',
    'minzoom': 0,
    'paint': {
        'line-color': '#489EA9',
        'line-width': 2
    }
});
```